# Passing POST request. Spting security. Rest template. Jackson converter

Tags: java, android, json, spring, jackson

I am begginer in Spring framework and I want ask you a question.
Ho do I pass properly POST request to register in DB my user.

I have a Android client and I found the only way how to work with web servises. 
I am using AsyncTask to manage a request.

But I don't know how to send the POST request with my `User` class to register him in data base.
Logic with data base already done.

I am asking you to help me how to post request and how manage him on the server.

So here is my code:

Server side, user controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserValidator userValidator;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public User registration(@RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        userValidator.validate(user, bindingResult);// here is validate logic
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            //What should i return here to my Android client ?
        }
        userService.save(user);
        securityService.autoLogin(user.getUserName(), user.getConfirmPassword());
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model, String error, String logout) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Username or password is incorrect.");
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            model.addAttribute("message", "Logged out successfully.");
        }

        return "login";// what should I return to the client ???
        //How my android client will understand that user is loged in ?
    }
}
```

Next I have client side(Here some MVP logic, but nvm):

```
public class CreateAccountPresenter implements CreateAccountContract.Presenter {
    private CreateAccountContract.View view;
    private String userName;
    private String userPassword;
    private String confirmUserPassword;


    public CreateAccountPresenter(CreateAccountContract.View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateAccountClick() {
        userName = view.getUserName();
        userPassword = view.getPassword();
        confirmUserPassword = view.getPasswordConfirmation();
        new CreateAccountTask().execute();

    }

    private class CreateAccountTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, User>{
        // How do I properly pass the post request with my User object ?
        @Override
        protected User doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            User user = new User(userName, userPassword, confirmUserPassword);
            return restTemplate.postForObject(URL.getUserRegistration(), user, User.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(User user) {
            view.makeToast("User registration complited " + user.getUserName());
        }
    }

}
```

Do I need initialize converter on the client side ? 
Asking for help, also will be awesome if you'll post some code in comments.

**UPDATE**
I change a little bit client side code, nad now I am getting next error on client side:

```
W/RestTemplate: POST request for "http://192.168.0.80:8080/user/registration" resulted in 400 (Bad Request); invoking error handler
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                  Process: com.example.user.userauthorisation, PID: 4676
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
                      at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:585)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
                      at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:348)
                      at com.example.user.userauthorisation.createaccount.CreateAccountPresenter$CreateAccountTask.doInBackground(CreateAccountPresenter.java:42)
                      at com.example.user.userauthorisation.createaccount.CreateAccountPresenter$CreateAccountTask.doInBackground(CreateAccountPresenter.java:35)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xeb89dde0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

And on server side:

```
2254021 [http-apr-8080-exec-2] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Unrecognized field "confirmationPassword" (class com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "id", "confirmPassword", "userName", "userPassword"])
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2cbfcb7c; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User["confirmationPassword"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "confirmationPassword" (class com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "id", "confirmPassword", "userName", "userPassword"])
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@2cbfcb7c; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: com.webserverconfig.user.entity.User["confirmationPassword"])
```

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your `User` bean but the error log shows that you are trying to access the field `confirmationPassword` while there is only `confirmPassword`. Check the getter name of your bean.

Comment: Yes, I've fix it. Now registration method working fine. I a, only have problem with login method.